# Powershell - suppress all onstart messages

Tags: powershell

I tried `pwsh -nologo ...` and this took care of default startup message.

But I have other 3rd party plugins (oh-my-posh, for example), and they have their own cmd to disable messages from this plugin `oh-my-posh disable notice`

Adding a "suppress" cmd for each plugin is not scalable, might miss here and there.

Anyone know if there is a way to suppress all messages on `pwsh` start? TIA

Comment: -nologo works for me. What are this 3 other plugins and how does your output look like?
Have you tried configuring the "profile file"? you can find the path of the profile file when you output the value of $profile in PowerShell

Comment: Maybe you can redirect the output streams (Verbose, Debug, Warning, Error) to `$null` or to a log file or something similar, but I'm not sure how useful it would be for you.

Comment: @DSSO21 something like these one's https://github.com/JanDeDobbeleer/oh-my-posh/discussions/2252#discussion-4066861

Comment: @MilosStojanovic redirecting to $null is not an option for me, as I invoke `pwsh -nolog <some custom cmdlet>` from my other code (Python, Ruby, etc.) and need to read the output of these cmdlets

Comment: Yeah, I thought so... just wanted to put it out there.

Comment: @mklement0 This is perfect, `-nologo -noprofile` combo is exactly what I need. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @scorpion35; I've written up a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For execute-and-exit uses of the  PowerShell CLI ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for *Windows PowerShell*, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for *PowerShell (Core) 7+*), with (possibly implicit)<sup>[1]</sup> `-File` or `-Command`,  you can use the **`-NoProfile`** CLI parameter, which suppresses loading of the [profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) files.

- In fact, in such invocations use of `-NoProfile` is *generally* advisable, both for reasons of performance and for providing a predictable execution environment.
- `-NoProfile` should be sufficient then: `-NoLogo` is *not* needed in combination with either `-File` or `-Command`, given that the logo (copyright) message is *not* shown with the latter parameters (except with `-File` if you *also* specify `-NoExit`, with the intent of entering an interactive session after script-file execution).

However, while `-NoProfile` will prevent visible output produced by code being run in your profiles, modules getting loaded *during execution of your code* could at least hypothetically still produce unwanted output (generally, they shouldn't). If so, you must either import them explicitly and silence the `Import-Module` call, or - if applicable and sufficient - (temporarily) turn off warnings, for instance, via `$WarningPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'`

In *interactive* shell sessions, where you obviously *do* want your profiles loaded, your best bet is to use the `-NoLogo` CLI parameter and to locate any visible output-producing commands inside your profile(s) and silence them individually, e.g. with `*>$null`, the silence-all-streams redirection.<sup>[2]</sup>

---

<sup>[1] If your command line contains neither `-File` nor `-Command` explicitly, which of the two parameters is *implied* when an argument following the CLI's own options is encountered depends on the PowerShell edition: *PowerShell 7+* assumes `-File` (execution of a *script file*), whereas *Windows PowerShell* assumes `-Command` (execution of a piece of PowerShell source code)</sup>

<sup>[2] Note that rogue commands that write directly to the host (console), e.g. with `Out-Host` or `[Console]::WriteLine`, will still produce visible output.</sup>

Comment: ha rouge commands. well said for badly written/placed code! Thank you